# SQLite: Query by 1 nearest hour on database but got data outside that time period

Tags: python, database, sqlite, time

The problem came when I work with SQLite in Python. I want to get data from 1 nearest hour (from 15:00:00 to 16:00:00 at that time I run my code).
My query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time > DATETIME('NOW', '-1 hour') ORDER BY time DESC
```

However, I got an outlier (10:59:00):
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtSkK.png)

Does anyone have any idea on this issue? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably your data are local datetimes so you must add to the `datetime()` function the `'localtime'` modifier:

```
DATETIME('NOW', '-1 hour', 'localtime')
```